# How to complete 2 http requests and then trigger another Action to merge the results

Tags: http, angular, typescript, ngrx

I have equivalent data types stored on 2 different databases.

- In a **SQL database**, I am storing a massive list of all foods.
- On a **Mongo database** I am storing an individual's food data which will
  override the default food data provided.

Both types of data will be stored in my ngrx store Application State as well as a Merged State.

```
export interface ApplicationState {
   allSQLFoodData: FoodData;
   allUserFoodData: FoodData;
   mergedFoodData: FoodData;
}
```

What I need to do, is to get the `allSQLFoodData` and the `allUserFoodData` from the backends, store those value to the state and also merge both sets of data in the merged state.

I'm doing this by `dispatch()`ing an action `INITIALIZE_DATA_ACTION` which I then listen for in an effect service.

Here is where I stand in my effect service:

**initialize-data-effect-service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class InitializeDataEffectService {

   @Effect() initialize$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
     .ofType(INITIALIZE_DATA_ACTION)
     .switchMap( (action) => {
      return Observable.combineLatest(
        this.foodService.loadSQLFoods( action.payload ),
        this.userDataService.loadUserData( action.payload )
      )
    })
    .switchMap(([allSQLFoodData, allUserData]) => {
      return Observable.of(
        new SQLFoodsLoadedAction( allSQLFoodData ),
        new UserDataLoadedAction( allUserData ),
        new BuildMergedFoodDataAction({sql: allSQLFoodData, user: allUserData})
      )
    })

  constructor( private actions$: Actions, private foodService: FoodService, private userDataService: UserDataService ) {

  }
}
```

As you can see, I am listening for the action of type `INITIALIZE_DATA_ACTION` and creating a combined observable using `combineLatest()` from the `http` responses. I then invoking the Action classes to set the Application state for each:

```
.switchMap(([allSQLFoodData, allUserData]) => {
  return Observable.of(
    new SQLFoodsLoadedAction( allSQLFoodData ),
    new UserDataLoadedAction( allUserData ),
    new BuildMergedFoodDataAction({sql: allSQLFoodData, user: allUserData})
  )
})
```

But this is giving the following error:

> The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the
>   usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.   Type
>   argument candidate 'SQLFoodsLoadedAction' is not a valid type argument
>   because it is not a supertype of candidate 'UserDataLoadedAction'.
>       Types of property 'payload' are incompatible.
>         Type 'AllUserData' is not assignable to type 'AllSQLFoodData'.
>           Property 'foods' is missing in type 'AllUserData'.

I'm not sure how to

> specifying the type arguments explicitly

and even if I did, I'm not sure how the `Effect()` decorator will now how to assign the results to the appropriate state values. **how can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return an observable from `switchMap` that emits multiple actions from the effect, use `Observable.from`, which can take an array:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';

...
.concatMap(([allSQLFoodData, allUserData]) => Observable.from([
  new SQLFoodsLoadedAction( allSQLFoodData ),
  new UserDataLoadedAction( allUserData ),
  new BuildMergedFoodDataAction({sql: allSQLFoodData, user: allUserData})
]))
```

Note that the `switchMap` is unecessary, as the returned observable will emit immediately. You can just use `concatMap`, instead.

Also, the effect doesn't assign anything to the state. Its only role is to emit actions. Those actions will be handled by reducers that will update the appropriate parts of the application's state.